# How to pass style attr from custom view over?

Tags: android

I'm creating a custom TextSwitcher as below

```
public class CustomTextSwitcher extends TextSwitcher {
    private static final long SHOW_TEXT_ANIMATION_TIME = 100;

    public CustomTextSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        in.setDuration(SHOW_TEXT_ANIMATION_TIME);
        out.setDuration(SHOW_TEXT_ANIMATION_TIME);

        this.setInAnimation(in);
        this.setOutAnimation(out);
    }

    public void setStyle(final int style) {
        this.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                return new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, style),
                        null, 0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is good, except I need to explicitly set the style using `setStyle` function as declared above, after initialization.

I'm hoping that I don't need to call `setStyle` but just declare my style in XML (as shown in code below) and get the int value through `attr` value got in constructor, and send it along to the `ViewFacory`, all done in `init()` function.

```
<my.example.CustomTextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/search_list_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/recentSearchHeaderText" />
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do so. It's as simple as `attrs.getStyleAttribute()`. Shown the code below

```
public class CustomTextSwitcher extends TextSwitcher {
    private static final long SHOW_TEXT_ANIMATION_TIME = 100;

    public CustomTextSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

        this.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                return new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, 
                        attrs.getStyleAttribute()), null, 0);
            }
        });
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        in.setDuration(SHOW_TEXT_ANIMATION_TIME);
        out.setDuration(SHOW_TEXT_ANIMATION_TIME);

        this.setInAnimation(in);
        this.setOutAnimation(out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeSet` you get from the Constructor is generated from the `style` attribute in XML along with the other attributes provided.  So you would just save it then pass it along in the [constructor to your TextView.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet)).  The `setStyle` method can actually be used with the [TextView#setTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(android.content.Context,%20int)) method which accepts style IDs. It will only look at style attributes that are associated with the `TextView`.  I would say this is easier than parsing through an AttributeSet and creating your own styles.