# Style used in Custom View is not send to constructor

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Custom View called `LoadingButton` extending `FrameLayout`. This class is inflatin custom XML layout containing `LinearLayout` and `ProgressBar` with parent `FrameLayout`. This should be functional as `Button`. I have custom defined styles for each Button type (changing background, tint, text color ...). I want to pass this style into my Custom View class. But it doesnt work. This type of constructor is not called. Instead general construtor with `Context` and `AttributeSet` is called.

Any explanation? I though if I add style into my custom View it will be automatically detected and different type of constructor is called.

Constructors:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        parseAttrs(context, attrs)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        parseAttrs(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    }
```

Usage of Custom View:

```
<com.project.custom.LoadingButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/button_blue_filled"
    app:l_buttonText="@string/text"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />
```

Comment: Check this answer, it might help in your case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910630/10271334